# Are there any features for developing HTML emails locally and using version control?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html, version-control

So far my work with Salesforce is for HTML emails in Content Builder. I don't see any obvious features that would allow our team to do various things that would help streamline development, such as:

- Version control for (master) templates and components (reference content)
- Develop and test locally, outside Content Builder and the browser
- Deployment using version control
- CSS inlining, minification, and other common features for email dev

It could be my access level, the features may exist, but searching around on the interwebs, I don't see any obvious leads so far to do with this.

The most immediate need for us is so we can document/comment our master templates. Since it seems there are limits in certain email clients, such as:

1. The total number of lines allowed
2. The total number of characters allowed
3. The cumulative size of the CSS

...we need a way to comment our code that doesn't interfere with these limits, which would mean stripping out the comments automatically for deployment (but retaining them in source).

But we also would benefit from minification and other features, which aren't in the web app (that I can tell), but always available locally.

Comment: Would love to also find a tool like this. Currently we build our templates locally (without any dynamic data), run all the email client tests and then once they're good to go, push them into Salesforce and hook them up with dynamic content.

Comment: @lu_ke____ Do you use a modular approach? So components having separate files? Or any sort of framework?

Comment: personally has been awhile since we've had to build email templates, but last time I threw together a quick `posthtml` tool to compile html components (in separate files) to a single `html` output file. The use of Visualforce Components is also a neat way to tackle the "component" development process. Can pass properties to them to fill text/images/blocks metadata quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consulted with a support representative of the Salesforce team, and they informed me that (as of March 2022) these features do not yet exist, as I suspected. They said they could become available features "in the near future", which would be great.

Fingers crossed. After all, Salesforce does recognize the [importance of version control](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/git-and-git-hub-basics/learn-why-version-control-is-important-for-team-based-development).

I will update this answer when the situation changes.